# Error Substates

Tags: javascript, ember.js, error-handling, ember-router

When an error occurs in a nested route, the thrown error bubbles up to parent routes until one of them catches it. 
The root level that can handle an error is `Application`'s. However, the `setupController` hook of `ApplicationRoute` is triggered after transitioning from `ErrorRoute` with an `undefined` context. 
Code example can be viewed here: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/2563/edit (output is given in the console) 
In `ApplicationRoute` I count on its initial model to be present after transitioning from the `ErrorRoute`. Why is it being reset to `undefined` and how can I solve it otherwise?

**Edit:**

Here's some relevant code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('articles');
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    /* model hook is not being called when the error bubbles up (nor afterModel hook) */
    /* This is the model expected in Application level */
    return [
      {"key1": "val1"},
      {"key2": "val2"},
      {"key3": "val3"}
    ];
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    /* This hook is called in the usual scenario, when ApplicationRoute first 
       invoked, with same model as defined in the model hook */
    /* However, it is also invoked after an error thrown from Articles Route,
       what happens then is:
       typeof model == "undefined" */
    console.log("SetupController invoked in Application Route:", model);    
  }
});

App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    /* The following throws the error */
    Ember.$.ajax("http://");
  }
});
```

Comment: Links are good, but relevant code should also be provided in the post body.

Answer (score 0):

The route never 'has' a model, it just has a model hook it uses for getting a model for the route.  When transitioning to an error no model's are attempted to be resolved (in case that's the error, you'd be in an infinite loop).

If your model is static content you can just set it in setupController.

Comment: Setting the model in `setupController` is not a good solution for me, as there will be a flicker in the template when the model resolved and its content injected to the page (as opposed to resolution in `model` hook, when the template only rendered after the promise returns).
Another problem is that `afterModel` hook is not being called here (can be seen in the attached `jsbin` example), which makes it also different than common transitions.

Comment: yeah, afterModel isn't called for the same reason.  I can see where this is a problem when you have real models in your application route, but how can you ever get to the error state if you have logic in the root which may be the cause of the error?

Comment: machty made the change, maybe the documentation will help https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945

Comment: a nested route causes the error, which is handled globally by `Application` after bubbling up.

Comment: Regarding machty's post, I think it's a bit outdated, as the scenario described above takes place in Ember's latest build (1.2). Although, he does provide there another way to tackle the issue (using `events` hash), which I might use if I can't find a way to solve it with `ErrorRoute` . Thanks!

Comment: You could always move all of your code 1 resource deeper so application is just a pass through resource and not dependent on the server etc, the problem is the error route lives under the application resource.